# UITableView data disappear when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Whenever I scroll in the table view, the cell label's text disappears
which means the tableview data disappears. I tried changing the `switch` statement to `if` statement and it still doesn't work. Is my function to change the date format the reason?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "requestsCell", for: indexPath) as! RequestsTableViewCell

    let requesten = requestsList[indexPath.row]

    switch requesten.type {
    case "FLT" :
        cell.requestType.text = "Flight"
        let reqDateTimeDate = stringToDate(strdate: requesten.reqDate!)
        cell.requestDate.text = "\(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: reqDateTimeDate))"
        cell.fromDate.isHidden = true
        cell.toDate.isHidden = true
    case "DOF" :
        cell.requestType.text = "Day Off"
        let reqDateTimeDate = stringToDate(strdate: requesten.reqDate!)

        cell.requestDate.text = "\(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: reqDateTimeDate))"
        cell.fromDate.isHidden = true
        cell.toDate.isHidden = true
    case "VAC" :
        cell.requestType.text = "Vacation"
        let reqDateFrom = stringToDate(strdate: requesten.dateFrom!)
        let reqDateTo = stringToDate(strdate: requesten.dateTo!)
        cell.requestDate.isHidden = true
        cell.toDate.text = "To: \(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: reqDateTo))"
        cell.fromDate.text = "From: \(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: reqDateFrom))"
    default:
        cell.requestType.text = ""
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you reloading the table data with the main thread on scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your code better such that each and every case statement changes the same properties. Or you need to override the `prepareForReuse` method so that each time the cell is reset to a common state.

Looking at your code - every case statement should assign these properties:

- requestType.text
- requestDate.text
- fromDate.isHidden
- fromDate.text
- toDate.isHidden
- toDate.text

Comment: can you give me more information about the prepareForReuse Method ?